# Behaviour of Caps-lock in Linux on VirtualBox, OSX Host

Tags: linux, macos, virtualbox, keyboard, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu under virtualbox on a MacBook Pro and I'm trying to
remap the Caps-Lock key to mod3 so I can use it as a replacement for the Alt
key in Xmonad. I can remap the keysyms but the problem I run into is that if
I press the Caps-Lock key then it generates a key down event immediately 
followed by a key release event. How can I prevent this behaviour? I want the
release event to occur when the key is actually released (as is the case for
other keys). Is this something that OSX is doing or is it some secret property
that is bound to the specific keycode in X?

I use xmodmap to unmap Super_R, map key code 66 to Super_R and then assign
Super_R to the mod3 modifier.

**Update**:

I worked around this by using [Seil](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/seil.html.en) in OSX to remap Caps-Lock to key code 110 (PC_APPLICATION). For some reason X remaps this to 135 but I could then remap Super_R to 135, turn off key repeat for 135 with "xset -r 135", and then assign Super_R to mod3.

PC_APPLICATION and Super_R were both picked just because I didn't use them for anything else, I think this should work with most or all key codes and key syms.

I've written a (much) longer explanation on how to do this [here](http://www.engabreen.se/2014/12/making-caps-lock-useful-untangling-the-mystery-of-key-remapping-in-osx-and-linux/).

---

I'm pretty sure that the key up/down behaviour of Caps-Lock is something X does.